# how do i unflatten a dataframe back to json/xml format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, xml

i am doing analysis on semi structured data, and for that i had to flatten both xml and json files to a pandas dataframe, now when the analysis is done, i do the improvement like drop null values and fix some data errors i need to generate xml or json files (depending on which format the user entered).

this is what i'm using to flatten xml :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


def flatten_xml(node, key_prefix=()):
    """
    Walk an XML node, generating tuples of key parts and values.
    """

    # Copy tag content if any
    text = (node.text or '').strip()
    if text:
        yield key_prefix, text

    # Copy attributes
    for attr, value in node.items():
        yield key_prefix + (attr,), value

    # Recurse into children
    for child in node:
        yield from flatten_xml(child, key_prefix + (child.tag,))


def dictify_key_pairs(pairs, key_sep='.'):
    """
    Dictify key pairs from flatten_xml, taking care of duplicate keys.
    """
    out = {}

    # Group by candidate key.
    key_map = defaultdict(list)
    for key_parts, value in pairs:
        key_map[key_sep.join(key_parts)].append(value)

    # Figure out the final dict with suffixes if required.
    for key, values in key_map.items():
        if len(values) == 1:  # No need to suffix keys.
            out[key] = values[0]
        else:  # More than one value for this key.
            for suffix, value in enumerate(values, 1):
                out[f'{key}{key_sep}{suffix}'] = value

    return out


# Parse XML with etree
tree = et.parse('NCT00571389.xml').iter()

# Generate flat rows out of the root nodes in the tree
rows = [dictify_key_pairs(flatten_xml(row)) for row in tree]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

and this is what i'm using to flatten json :

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import json

def flatten_json(nested_json, exclude=['']):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude: flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out

f = open('employee_data.json') 
this_dict = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in this_dict[list(this_dict.keys())[0]]])
```

i need to know how to go from a dataframe to the original structure of the files, help please?

edit:
this is the example of the json file i'm using:

```
{"features": [{"candidate": {"first_name": "Margaret", "last_name": "Mcdonald", "skills": ["skLearn", "Java", "R", "SQL", "Spark", "C++"], "state": "AL", "specialty": "Database", "experience": "Mid", "relocation": "no"}}, {"candidate": {"first_name": "Michael", "last_name": "Carter", "skills": ["TensorFlow", "R", "Spark", "MongoDB", "C++", "SQL"], "state": "AR", "specialty": "Statistics", "experience": "Senior", "relocation": "yes"}}]}
```

and this is the columns after i flatten them:

```
candidate.first_name
candidate.last_name
candidate.skills.0
candidate.skills.1
candidate.skills.2
candidate.skills.3
candidate.skills.4
candidate.skills.5
candidate.state
candidate.specialty
candidate.experience
candidate.relocation
candidate.skills.6
candidate.skills.7
candidate.skills.8
```

Comment: have you checked the `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` method? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: @FlavioMoraes it won't work since my columns look like `candidate.first_name` `candidate.skills.0`, so i need to split them then join the keys that have the same start together

Comment: can you provide an example of a json? It will be easier to see how it looks like before and after flattening

Comment: @FlavioMoraes hello, i just added an example

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was not easy and I should have guided you instead of coding it for you, but here is what I've done:

```
json = {"features": [{"candidate": {"first_name": "Margaret", "last_name": "Mcdonald", "skills": ["skLearn", "Java", "R", "SQL", "Spark", "C++"], "state": "AL", "specialty": "Database", "experience": "Mid", "relocation": "no"}}, {"candidate": {"first_name": "Michael", "last_name": "Carter", "skills": ["TensorFlow", "R", "Spark", "MongoDB", "C++", "SQL"], "state": "AR", "specialty": "Statistics", "experience": "Senior", "relocation": "yes"}}]}
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in json[list(json.keys())[0]]])


import re
header = df.columns
print(header)
regex = r'(\w+)\.(\w+)\.?(\d+)?'
m=re.findall(regex,'\n'.join(header))

def make_json(json,feature,pos,value):
    if pos+1 == len(feature):
        json[feature[pos]] = value
        return json
    elif feature[pos+1] == '':
        json[feature[pos]] = value
        return json
    elif feature[pos+1].isdigit():
        if feature[pos+1] == '0':
            json[feature[pos]] = [value]
            return json
        else:
            json[feature[pos]].append(value)
            return json
    else:
        if feature[pos] not in json:
            json[feature[pos]] = make_json({},feature,pos+1,value)
            return json
        else:
            json[feature[pos]] = make_json(json[feature[pos]],feature,pos+1,value)
            return json

json = {'features': []}
for row in range(len(df)):
    cadidate = {}
    for col, feature in enumerate(m):
        cadidate = make_json(cadidate,feature,0,df.iloc[row][header[col]])
    json['features'].append(cadidate)

print(json)
```

You see I wanted to make it in a recursive way so it can work for more complex json, as long you define the regex right. For your specific example it could be simpler.